# 22.10 My audio stops working, have to pkill browser and pipewire to get it going again

Tags: sound, 22.10, pipewire

I've noticed that sometimes when there is a system sound, my audio stops working. I have to kill the app with the audio and pipewire, and then restart the app.

It happens quite often.  Yoga C930, ubuntu 22.10, Linux darkle 6.0.9-060009-generic #202211161102 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 16 12:14:18 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
[18901.556488] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000
[19775.560140] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: ipc FW reply: 6 FW Error Code: 3007
[19775.560176] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: ipc: set pipeline state failed, err: -22
[19795.712750] snd_soc_skl 0000:00:1f.3: MCPS Budget Violation: 9b050000
```

Comment: Raised the question in the Fedora community too: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/audio-crash-for-pipewire-with-intel-hda-dmic-on-skylake/29881